# Regular expression missing characters

Tags: c#, regex

Below code works when the regular expression match with the string. What if one of the characters are not there, for example MONEY-STAT is missing?

```
string s = "MONEY-ID123456:MONEY-STAT43:MONEY-PAYetr-1232832938";
Regex regex =
    new Regex(@"MONEY-ID(?<moneyId>.*?)\:MONEY-STAT(?<moneyStat>.*?)\:MONEY-PAYetr-(?<moneyPaetr>.*?)$");
Match match = regex.Match(s);
if (match.Success)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Money ID: " + match.Groups["moneyId"].Value);


    Console.WriteLine("Money Stat: " + match.Groups["moneyStat"].Value);
    Console.WriteLine("Money Paetr: " + match.Groups["moneyPaetr"].Value);

}

Console.WriteLine("hit <enter>");
Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: Then it will not match and won't execute the code within `if(match.Success) { ... }`

Comment: why don't you try by yourself?

Comment: @Steve B won't work, if the string does not work. Anything I can change with the regular expression string?

Comment: So you question is not "What if one of the characters are not there?" but "What is the correct regex to extract my values?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed `MONEY-STAT` to `(?:MONEY-STAT)?`

```
MONEY-ID(?<moneyId>.*?)\:(?:MONEY-STAT)?(?<moneyStat>.*?)\:MONEY-PAYetr-(?<moneyPaetr>.*?)$
```

explain:

```
(?: subexpression)        Defines a noncapturing group. 
?                         Matches the previous element zero or one time.
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I misunderstand your question.. but does this suit you?

```
(MONEY-ID(?<moneyId>.*?)\:)?(MONEY-STAT(?<moneyStat>.*?)\:)?(MONEY-PAYetr-)?(?<moneyPaetr>.*?)$
```

It basically makes each token optional.. It also includes the colon, since that's obviously a delimiter of some kind.

**DISCLAIMER**
I am terrible at regular expressions.. but this worked from my test here: http://ideone.com/0pdFk

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
(MONEY-ID[\d]+|(:?)MONEY-STAT[\d]+|:MONEY-PAYetr-[\d]+)
```

This will match patterns like below:

> MONEY-ID123456:MONEY-STAT43:MONEY-PAYetr-1232832938
>
> MONEY-STAT43:MONEY-PAYetr-1232832938
>
> MONEY-ID123456:MONEY-PAYetr-1232832938